# angular two-way bind with isolate scope appears to be one-way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a simple click-to-edit directive using an isolate scope so that it's reusable. When I use it, the source value ( '=' ) in the controller scope is never updated, though its original value is applied within the directive. It's as if the binding is one-way ( '@' ).

Here's the code:

```
app.directive("ngClickToEdit", function() {
    return {
        template:
            '<div>' +
                '<div ng-show="enabled">' +
                    '<input ng-change="validator()" ng-blur="enabled=false"  ng-model="source"/>' +
                '</div>' +
                    '<div ng-show="!enabled" ng-bind="source" ng-click="enable()"></div>' +
            '</div>',
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            validator: '&',
            source: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.enabled = false;

            var input = element.children()[0].firstChild;

            scope.enable = function() {
                scope.enabled = true;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    input.focus();
                    input.select();
                }, 200);
            };
        },
    };
});
```

Here is an invocation in the controller (edited to wrap in ng-if div block):

```
<div ng-if='name'>
    <ng-click-to-edit validator='validateName()' source='name' />
</div>
```

When validateName() in the controller scope is invoked the value of 'name' is the original value and not the (changed) value in the directive's input control. The model is not updated. Why?

**Resolved**:
The ng-if block creates a child scope, passing `name` as a string primitive due to [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance). Passing an object reference into the directive solves the problem. See a [revised plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KaSinjjERKb1MxsgXR8v?p=preview) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because outer scope's `name` has not yet been assigned the inner scope's `source`. When you declare an isolate scope with `"="`, Angular `$watch`es for changes (see [code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1960)) in both values and does the two-way binding, but the $watches haven't yet fired when `validator` is invoked.

You can check it with this code:

```
$scope.validateName = function(){
  console.log("outside directive: name = " + $scope.name);

  $timeout(function(){
    console.log("but just after digest cycle: name = " + $scope.name);
  });
};
```

There are a few things you could do:

1) You could fire validator after `$timeout`:

```
scope.localValidate = function(){
   $timeout(function(){ scope.validator(); });
};
```

and the template:

```
<input ng-change="localValidate()"..>
```

2) You could $watch for changes in `source` and then fire the `$validator` (instead of in `ng-change`):

```
scope.$watch("source", function(){
    scope.validator();
});
```

3) You could pass the value to validate into the validator function:

```
<input ng-change="validator({name: source})"..>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I realize I'd neglected to mention that the controller value _never_ changes, so I don't think it's a timing issue. After each call it's always the original value, as if the $watch in the directive is not updating the source ever.Thoughts?

Comment: It changed when I copied your code to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fHHbCEuKA1eBQyzATKaD?p=preview). Can you create a plunker to reproduce your issue?

Comment: here's the output from your test:

outside directive: name = nnnnm
but just after digest cycle: name = nnnnm

Comment: what is `nnnnm` - the original value? I just tried it with a link I provided in the comment above and this is NOT what I observe.

Comment: Yes, `nnnnm` is the original value in the controller scope. I added the $watch of `source` as you suggested and the results are the same...

Comment: Please create a plunker with your code (or confirm that you are using the link I created - this works for me on Chrome/IE/Firefox).

Comment: Indeed, your example (my code) works in the plunker link. I need to determine why it works there, but not in my app. I will do that and report back. Thanks for the help. Stay tuned...

Comment: Okay, I have discovered that the isolate scope linkage breaks when wrapped by an `ng-if='name'` directive. Please see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGmDivU9HltpGB2V1Kop) for an example.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your particular directive or with digest cycles. This has to do with the fact that `ng-if` creates a new child scope and when you change `name` it remains in the child scope of `ng-if` - this is how prototypical inheritance works with primitives like string. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1uDRLMPjesp2nBtP8J2?p=preview) that illustrates this.

Comment: You beat me to it. I passed an object instead of a primitive (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KaSinjjERKb1MxsgXR8v?p=preview)) and the linkage works. Thanks!